# Authentication Event Listener

Tags: jquery, ajax, sequelize.js

I am currently trying to make two event handlers: One for when a user signs up and a new account is made and another for when a user attempts to login. As of this writing, nothing occurs when invalid credentials are implemented and a new user is made, but not getting stored in the database. Can someone explain what the signUp() and auth() methods are doing?

```
'use strict';
var userService = window.skilly.userService;
const _ = require('lodash');

$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#signup').on('click', function(event) {
        /* stop form from submitting normally */
                // event.preventDefault();

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            // var $form = $(this),
            //     term = $form.find('input[name="s"]').val(),
            //     url = $form.attr('action');
             var user = _.object($("#myForm").serializeArray().map(function (v) {
                return [v.name, v.value];
            }));



            /* Send the data using post */
             var signUp = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://skilly-rayman504.c9users.io/user',
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log(user);
                }
            })
            userService.signUp(user);
    })
    $('#login').on('click', function(event) {
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
            // event.preventDefault();

            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    event.preventDefault();
    var creds = _.object($("#form-signin").serializeArray().map(function (v) {
        return [v.name, v.value];
    }));
    $('#btn-close-auth').trigger('click');

            // /* Send the data using post */
             var auth = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://skilly-rayman504.c9users.io/user/auth',
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log(user);
                }
            })
        userService.auth(creds);
   })
})
```

Comment: This looks like jquery to me.  If so, you probably ought to add the jquery tag.  One thing that it is NOT is SQL, so you probably ought to remove the SQL tag as well.